# SQLite3 (python) query to search multiple columns in one SELECT statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to create an address book and I'd need to check if a given input can be found in all of three columns of the table i created:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("Address_Book.db")
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE addresses (
        name text,
        number text,
        email text)
    """)

    conn.commit()

c.execute("SELECT rowid, * FROM addresses WHERE name LIKE (?)", ('%' + self + '%',))          
res = c.fetchall()
```

In the above code I'm only searching the 'name' column. I tried writing 'name, number, email' but maybe I don't know the correct syntax and couldn't find it online. I found a way around the problem but it's not that elegant, so I hope someone can help, thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try concatenation `name||number||email` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple workaround for your SQL query would be using the OR operator. As an example, please have a look at the following query

```
SELECT * from addresses where name LIKE '%A%'
OR number LIKE '%A%'
OR email LIKE '%A%'
```

Comment: @Grinch Glad to hear that. Can you please accept my solution as correct, if it works?